# Percentage Increase Calculator is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a Jquery Percentage increase calculator from a initial value.
Example : 1000 + 10% = 1100, 1000 + 25% = 1250, 1000 + 39 = 1390 ... etc..
Unfortunately my codes are not working. Please check this Codepen link https://codepen.io/coderco/pen/JjLJxXj . Here is my codes. Please help me..

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="Amount" value="">
<input type="text" value="10.45" id="Discount">
<input type="text" id="Result">
```

**Script**

```
$(document).on("change keyup blur", "#Discount", function() {
    var main = $('#Amount').val();
    var disc = $('#Discount').val();
    var dec = (disc / 100); //toFixed(0) == its convert 10 into 0.10
    var mult = main * dec; // gives the value for subtract from main value
    var discont = main + mult;
    $('#Result').val(discont.toFixed(0));
});
```

Comment: If you are going to tell us it's not working, then tell us why, rather that let us stew in ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is working once you realize for some reason `discont` is a string. Also I improved the event used.

```js
$(document).on("input", "#Discount", function() {
  var main = Number($('#Amount').val());
  var disc = Number($('#Discount').val());
  var dec = (disc / 100); 
  var mult = main * dec; 
  var discont = main + mult;
  // alert(typeof discont) // seems it's a string
  $('#Result').val(Number(discont).toFixed(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Amount" value="">
<input type="text" value="10.45" id="Discount">
<input type="text" id="Result">
```